# ConfigureAwait(False) doesn't change context after ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or I found a bug in the Async library, but I have seen an issue  when running some async code after I came back to the Synchronized context with continueWith().

**UPDATE: The code now runs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFrameController controller = new MainFrameController(this);
        //First async call without continueWith
        controller.DoWork();

        //Second async call with continueWith
        controller.DoAsyncWork();
    }

    public void Callback(Task<HttpResponseMessage> task)
    {
        Console.Write(task.Result); //IT WORKS

        MainFrameController controller =
            new MainFrameController(this);
        //third async call
        controller.DoWork(); //IT WILL DEADLOCK, since ConfigureAwait(false) in HttpClient DOESN'T  change context
    }
}


internal class MainFrameController
{
    private readonly Form1 form;

    public MainFrameController(Form1 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public void DoAsyncWork()
    {
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());
        CallbackWithAsyncResult(task);
    }

    private void CallbackWithAsyncResult(Task<HttpResponseMessage> asyncPrerequisiteCheck)
    {
        asyncPrerequisiteCheck.ContinueWith(task =>
            form.Callback(task),
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage DoWork()
    {
        MyHttpClient myClient = new MyHttpClient();
        return myClient.RunAsyncGet().Result;
    }
}

internal class MyHttpClient
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsyncGet()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        return await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.no").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

partial class Form1
{
    private IContainer components;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

- The HttpClient code which is async runs well the first time.
- Then, I run the second async code and return to the UI context with ContinueWith, and it works well.
- I run the HttClient code again, but it deadlock because this time ConfigureAwait(false) does not change the context.

Comment: It would be nice if this were an actual *complete* example that demonstrates the problem. Unfortunately, it isn't, so we'd be left guessing. If you could, please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, it would be nice to know, what you would really like to achieve. Since you are mixing different techniques for async operations and the code is kind of hard to follow. For example RunAsyncPost method is called as DoHttpWork.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem in your code is due to `StartNew` and `ContinueWith`. `ContinueWith` is dangerous for the same reasons that [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I describe on my blog.

In summary: **`StartNew` and `ContinueWith` should only be used if you're doing [dynamic task-based parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx)** (which this code is not).

The *actual* problem is that `HttpClient.GetAsync` doesn't use (the equivalent of) `ConfigureAwait(false)`; it's using `ContinueWith` with its the default scheduler argument (which is `TaskScheduler.Current`, **not** `TaskScheduler.Default`).

To explain in more detail...

The default scheduler for `StartNew` and `ContinueWith` is *not* `TaskScheduler.Default` (the thread pool); it's `TaskScheduler.Current` (the current task scheduler). So, in your code, `DoAsyncWork` as it currently is does *not* always execute `DoWork` on the thread pool.

The first time `DoAsyncWork` is called, it will be called on the UI thread but *without a current `TaskScheduler`*. In this case, `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, and `DoWork` is called on the thread pool.

Then, `CallbackWithAsyncResult` invokes `Form1.Callback` with a `TaskScheduler` that runs it on the UI thread. So, when `Form1.Callback` calls `DoAsyncWork`, it is called on the UI thread *with* a current `TaskScheduler` (the UI task scheduler). In this case, `TaskScheduler.Current` is the UI task scheduler, and `DoAsyncWork` ends up calling `DoWork` *on the UI thread*.

For this reason, **you should always specify a `TaskScheduler` when calling `StartNew` or `ContinueWith`**.

So, this is a problem. But it's not actually causing the deadlock you're seeing, because `ConfigureAwait(false)` *should* allow this code to just block the UI instead of deadlocking.

It's deadlocking because Microsoft *made the same mistake*. Check out line 198 [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/HttpClient/0.6.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs?ImageName=System.Net.Http): `GetContentAsync` (which is called by `GetAsync`) uses `ContinueWith` without specifying a scheduler. So, it's picking up the `TaskScheduler.Current` from your code, and will not ever complete its task until it can run on that scheduler (i.e., the UI thread), causing the classic deadlock.

There's nothing you can do to fix the `HttpClient.GetAsync` bug (obviously). You'll just have to work around it, and the easiest way to do that is to avoid having a `TaskScheduler.Current`. Ever, if you can.

Here's some general guidelines for asynchronous code:

- Don't ever use `StartNew`. Use `Task.Run` instead.
- Don't ever use `ContinueWith`. Use `await` instead.
- Don't ever use `Result`. Use `await` instead.

If we just do minimal changes (replacing `StartNew` with `Run` and `ContinueWith` with `await`), then `DoAsyncWork` *always* executes `DoWork` on the thread pool, and the deadlock is avoided (since `await` uses the `SynchronizationContext` directly and not a `TaskScheduler`):

```
public void DoAsyncWork()
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = Task.Run(() => DoWork());
    CallbackWithAsyncResult(task);
}

private async void CallbackWithAsyncResult(Task<HttpResponseMessage> asyncPrerequisiteCheck)
{
    try
    {
        await asyncPrerequisiteCheck;
    }
    finally
    {
        form.Callback(asyncPrerequisiteCheck);
    }
}
```

However, it's always questionable to have a callback scenario with Task-based asynchrony, because Tasks themselves have the power of callbacks within them. It looks like you're trying to do a sort of asynchronous initialization; I have a blog post on [asynchronous construction](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that shows a few possible approaches.

Even something really basic like this would be a better design than callbacks (again, IMO), even though it uses `async void` for initialization:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFrameController controller = new MainFrameController();
        controller.DoWork();

        Callback(controller.DoAsyncWork());
    }

    private async void Callback(Task<HttpResponseMessage> task)
    {
        await task;
        Console.Write(task.Result);

        MainFrameController controller = new MainFrameController();
        controller.DoWork();
    }
}

internal class MainFrameController
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoAsyncWork()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => DoWork());
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage DoWork()
    {
        MyHttpClient myClient = new MyHttpClient();
        var task = myClient.RunAsyncGet();
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

Of course, there's other design problems here: namely, `DoWork` is blocking on a naturally-asynchronous operation, and `DoAsyncWork` is blocking a thread pool thread on a naturally-asynchronous operation. So, when `Form1` calls `DoAsyncWork`, it's awaiting a thread pool task that's blocked on an asynchronous operation. Async-over-sync-over-async, that is. You may also benefit from my [blog series on `Task.Run` etiquette](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Comment: There was so much going on here, I was waiting for you to post a clear analysis. The OP's code (with its mix of async mechanisms) seems to have been "clearly" designed to *create* a deadlock, it was unclear to me if a "fix" would be possible. The only point I might have included in a separate answer is that they seem to believe `ConfigureAwait` shifts things onto a separate context when in fact it's almost the opposite - "if we can't get back to the original context, that's okay", in the event the waiting even happens.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Excellent point; I was going to mention that but forgot with all the words in this answer. :)  @op: `ConfigureAwait(false)` does *not* change the context. It only informs the `await` to not capture the context. In particular, if the task is already completed, an `await ...ConfigureAwait(false)` will *not* move to a thread pool thread.

Comment: Thank you, This is what I was looking for, I was not interested in fixing this code, it was just an example. 
I wanted to understand why it was deadlocking. And of course learn better the use of the async tools :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.Result`. If you have any code at all that uses async/await, just completely forget it even exists. Even if we get it working today, what you are trying to do will be so incredibly brittle that it won't necessarily work tomorrow.

Comment: the .Result runs under Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());, so it should not matter, it will be in another context. so the UI will not wait for it.

Comment: It is not about what I am trying to do, I am trying to understand why the 3rd call goes in deadlock. and why the ConfigureAwait(false) is not avoiding that

Comment: @Max.Moraga - I'm not sure what you think `ConfigureAwait` does but you should be aware that its only noticeable effects are within the same method as where it's called. As such, calling `ConfigureAwait` just before the method exits is (mostly) pointless.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

According to this blog, the call to 
return await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.no").ConfigureAwait(false);

should run the GetAsync in a different context, so there is no deadlock, but it does not change the context, so the whole thing frozes forever

Comment: @Max.Moraga - but since `return await` (when the only `await` in a method) is an anti-pattern and just forces us to create the whole continuation machinery pointlessly, you could re-write that method without `async` and `await` and it will have the same semantics - except for not having to create a *continuation* for the current method, and it's *that* continuation that is the only thing affected by `ConfigureAwait`. Neither our method's callers nor methods that our method calls into are affected by what `ConfigureAwait` does.